# Deleted Topology and Feature Classes are still locked within Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I deleted my topology within a geodatabase rather than disconnecting the feature classes inside of it. Doing this appeared to have deleted all 4 feature classes that were within the topology entirely from the geodatabase. I was able to find a backup of the geodatabase, but now when I try to export the replacement feature class into the original geodatabase, I am getting the error that a feature class with that same name already exists. Except it does not appear within the geodatabase and I have checked in both ArcCatalog and ArcMap. How do I locate these feature classes that are deleted but still somehow locked within the geodatabase?

Comment: What version? And was the topology versioned?